# TFS Dashboard Widgets: Query the TFS_Warehouse db?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, tfs

(Warning:  SQL Server expert, TFS Dashboard Widget Noob)

My workplace has a TFS setup (version 15.117.27024.0) where there are dashboards with widgets where we can use Shared Queries as a data source.  No problems here.

Question:  Is it possible to configure a widget so that the source query is a custom Stored Procedure in TFS_Warehouse?

Thanks in advance. 
Jim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of a way to return the results of a stored proc in the TFS_Warehouse or other DB directly from a widget.

We use Otto Streifel's [Wiql Editor extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ottostreifel.wiql-editor#overview) ([source](https://github.com/ostreifel/wiql-editor)) which allows us to write WIQL queries instead of clicking our way through the GUI that is provided to create our shared queries. The [syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/wiql-syntax?view=vsts) is similar to SQL, but it is more limited than a SQL stored proc would be. Even so, we have been able to write some robust queries to create some very useful widgets. (For example to break out how many hours we have planned/worked based on tags applied to our work items)

The only other solution I could think of would be to use a `Embedded Web page` widget that would call the stored proc and display the results.

Comment: Thanks for posting.  I'm not the admin here so I'll have to speak to the guy that is, as when I attempt to download I get a 'We did not find an organization for which you are an owner or a member.' message. 

I was able to pull off saving a Saved Query as a .wiql file, reading the WIQL, and reverse engineering an appropriate SQL Server Stored Procedure.  Good to go on a couple of reports. 

My limitation right now is that I can't query work item status changes by day, as it only shows the most recent status, and I have a requirement to crank out some graphs on work items by status.

Comment: (continuation) and I can custom build it in TFS_Warehouse by creating another Fact table, but that would mean I'd be using TFS_Warehouse as the data source, which works for SSRS reporting but my employer has fallen in love with the dashboard.

Comment: @JimHorn No, we can only use the basic work item query in dashboard, **Brandon**'s workaround looks good...

Comment: Ok.  That still doesn't solve my root problem for the moment as I need to query TFS_Warehouse as opposed to getting real creative in saved queries, but it is the correct answer to the question.  Although if I dig deeper into the transactional db schema maybe I'll figure out a query that meets my needs. 
 Appreciate it.  -Jim